# Why are even numbers closed under multiplication?

Tags: vector-spaces, terminology

I'm a little bit confused about why even numbers are closed under multiplication.

Closure under multiplication is $$\lambda u \ \in V   $$ where $V$ is a vector space. If $\lambda = 1.5$, then $\lambda u$ is an odd number right? Therefore, it should not be closed under multiplication?

Comment: 1.5 isn't even.

Comment: Even integers are only closed under multiplication by **even** integers. And no need to mix it with vector spaces.

Comment: The closure under multiplication is meant for a group or a ring, not a vector space.

Comment: Does $\lambda$ necessarily have to be even? I thought just the result has to be even.

Answer (score 2):

A closed binary operation merely means that the elements remain in the same set, which is to say the operation is a function of the form $X \times X \rightarrow X$. So for example the natural numbers are closed under addition because when you add two naturals numbers together the answer is still a natural number.

In this case the even numbers are closed under multiplication because $2m \times 2n = 2(2mn)$ which is even.